# Simple trigger in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, triggers, sql-server-2008-r2

Can anybody tell me how can I update a column of a record when it is inserted to the database.
Here's the pseudocode that I want.

```
if( mytable.OriginalId == null )
    mytable.OriginalId = Scope_Identity();
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx

Comment: There is a problem here: AFAIK you can only fetch the generated identity on a AFTER UDPATE trigger - so you would have to execute another update on the table to change `OriginalId`... It's feasible, but I would not advise that. I would recommend a third, computed column in that case, with the expression `COALESCE(OriginalID, ID)`. Simpler, no trigger required, and it would give you the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

This would be contradictory I think. Either OriginalId is set or it isn't on insert.

If it isn't where does `Scope_Identity()` get it's value from? If it's from another column then would it not be better to use a computed column?

Sorry, it's not clear what the overall objective is... you would not normally use a trigger especially if OriginalId is part of the PK

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned. The PK is another column called "Id".

Comment: Thanks. And should OriginalId always be the same as ID? or different?

Comment: If the user sets it to null it should be the same as ID otherwise it should be whatever user wants.